# Is it possible to simplify expressions using the sympy library, for example sqrt (x^2) = abs (x)?

Tags: python-3.x, sympy, symbols, sqrt

I reviewed the sympy documentation and did not find such a thing. Using the simplify method, sqrt(x**2) does not change.

Comment: If you let sympy know that `x` is just a real (`x = symbols('x', real=True)`, then `(sqrt(x**2)).simplify()` seems to result in `Abs(x)`.

Comment: Is it possible to define variables as real if you enter an expression through the string: sqrt(simplify('x**2')).simplify()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you are hoping that `sqrt(x**2)` will simplify to `x`. The problem is that this is not a valid simplification in general e.g.:

```py
In [23]: z = -1

In [24]: z**2
Out[24]: 1

In [25]: sqrt(z**2)
Out[25]: 1

In [26]: sqrt(z**2) == z
Out[26]: False
```

When declaring a symbol you can set assumptions that are needed for simplification like this to be possible:

```py
In [27]: x = Symbol('x', real=True)

In [28]: y = Symbol('y', positive=True)

In [29]: sqrt(x**2)
Out[29]: │x│

In [30]: sqrt(y**2)
Out[30]: y
```

Comment: Is it possible to define variables as real if you enter an expression through the string: sqrt(simplify('x**2')).simplify()?

Comment: It is possible if you use `parse_expr` explicitly.

Comment: This code gives sqrt(a**2), I need it to give abs(a).
<code>from sympy import sqrt, simplify, symbols
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
a = symbols('a', real=True)
expr = parse_expr('a**2')
sqrt(simplify(expr)).simplify()</code>

Comment: Better to ask a new question. The question as asked here is answered.